# How to compare means, variances and standard deviations of durations for statistical significance

Tags: self-study, variance, survival, standard-deviation, mean

I am trying to compare multiple mean values, variance and standard deviation values
for statistical significance. For example I have the following data:

Data 1

- **Mean:**            0.01304
- **Sample Variance:** 0.000504324897959184
- **Standard Deviation:** 0.0224571792075315

Data 2

- **Mean:**            1.17498
- **Sample Variance:** 0.180901244489796
- **Standard Deviation:** 0.425324869352588

How can I compare them?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook?  Even if not, for questions like this you should probably add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Using only sample statistics, you will need to make assumptions. You will also need the $n$'s from the 2 datasets. Do you have that?

Comment: @gung Yes I have the n's. The n for both the above data is 50. I need to compare the information above to come to a conclusion. I just don't know how to compare them. are there any formulas or techniques? I have the entire data set from which mean, variance and standard deviation was calculated.

Comment: Is this question from a course or textbook? What software do you have access to? You would do better to work with the full dataset rather than just the summary statistics.

Comment: @gung  its not from any course or textbook. I collected the data myself. The data represents HTTP requests times for 2 different web frameworks. The above means, variance and standard deviation were calculated from the data set using EXCEL.

Comment: So is each data point a duration (eg the time between 1 request and the next)? If they are durations, do you have any censored data (ie, cases where the duration was longer than you were willing to wait & so you either threw them out or said >cutoff)?

Comment: @gung  Yes, each data point is duration in "Seconds". For above both data 1 and data 2 I have 50 durations each data set. So in total I have 100 durations (50 EACH data set). The data is not censored yet. First I want to compare the data without censoring and after that I censor the data and compare again to show the difference between both comparisons. The only issue is I don't know how to actually compare the means, variances etc. And even if I compare them what are they telling me? I have never done this kind of statistical analysis before.

Answer (score 1):

Because your data are durations, you should use methods from [survival analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis).  A $t$-test is unlikely to be appropriate.  I doubt this can be done in Excel.  It isn't hard to do in R, however, and R is free.  You should download R from [here](http://www.r-project.org/).  [This guide](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/) should be simple and quick enough to give you what you will need.

What you want is to use a [log rank test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-rank_test).  In R that's [?survdiff](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/survdiff.html).  You may also want to plot and examine the [Kaplan-Meier survival curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator).  In R, you can use [?survfit](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/survival/html/survfit.html) and then `plot()`.  Here's a quick demonstration from the R documentation:

```r
# install.packages(survival)  # if necessary
library(survival)

leukemia.surv <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml) 
windows()
  plot(leukemia.surv, lty = 2:3) 
  legend(100, .9, c("Maintenance", "No Maintenance"), lty = 2:3) 
  title("Kaplan-Meier Curves\nfor AML Maintenance Study")
```

[image]

```r
survdiff(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)
# Call:
#   survdiff(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)
# 
#                  N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
# x=Maintained    11        7    10.69      1.27       3.4
# x=Nonmaintained 12       11     7.31      1.86       3.4
# 
# Chisq= 3.4  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.0653
```